# In general, we cannot substitute a matrix $B$ into $P(x)=Q(x)R(x)$. But in this case I think we can substitute a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I am reading "Introduction to Linear Algebra" (in Japanese) by Masahiko Saito.
The following theorem is in this book:

> Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial with $n\times n$ complex matrix coefficients such that
> $$P(x) = P_0 x^k + P_1 x^{k-1} + \dots + P_{k-1} x + P_k, P_0\neq O.$$
>
> If $P(x) = P_1(x) (I x - B) + P$, then $$P=P_0 B^k+P_1 B^{k-1}+\dots+P_{k-1} B+P_k.$$

The author wrote we cannot calculate as follows because matrix mutiplication is not commutative:

> $P(B)=P_1(B)(I B-B)+P=P_1(B) O + P =O+P=P.$

Let $P(x) = Q(x) R(x)$.
In general, we cannot substitute a matrix $B$ into $P(x)=Q(x)R(x)$.
But when $P(x)=P_1(x) (Ix-B)$, I think we can substitute any matrix $C$ into $P(x)=P_1(x) (Ix-B)$.
So, we can substitute $B$ as follows:
$P(B) = P_1(B)(IB-B)=O$.

Am I wrong?